# Jquery: Appending and replacing <img> dynamically

Tags: jquery, navigation, image, html-lists

We want to have drop down indicator (arrow) to our NAV that have submenus. Also changing that indicator whenever it has a class of current.

We have a code like this

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Company Profile</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="drop">Products</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products 3</a></li>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>      
</nav>
```

Dynamically we want to append an IMG on LIs that have sa submenus the resulting to a code like this

```
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Company Profile</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="drop">Products
            <img src="li_gray.png">
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products 3</a></li>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>      
    </nav>
```

Finally we want the indicator arrow to also change when that LI's class="current". Code looking something like this: **note that the IMG src had been change to li_white.png

```
<nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Company Profile</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="drop current">Products
                <img src="li_white.png">
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products 3</a></li>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>      
        </nav>
```

Comment: be careful, your html is not valid, you are not closing some of the `<ul>`s .

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that instead of appending/changing images, you should just use **image-backgrounds in css**. You can then easily change the background image depending on the status of the link (hover, current etc), and changing it later on will nto involve any javascript or server side manipulation of your markup.

Even better, use [CSS image sprites](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/) !

**UPDATE :**

here is an example (without CSS sprites) :
http://jsfiddle.net/tsimbalar/JBcqB/

the idea is to add a special CSS class for links that have a sub-navigation, and do all the styling in CSS based on that class.

UPDATE 2

and here **using CSS sprites** (in that case, the icons from jQuery UI). In that case, we just "change" the position of the background on `:hover` , revealing another icon.

http://jsfiddle.net/tsimbalar/gw686/

**we actually DO need a bit of javascript** to conditionnally check whether a link has a subnavigation or not.

**UPDATE 3+4**

It does not seem to work properly with IE (surprising...), but I think it is because you use HTML5 tags like `nav`, which can not be styled in IE without first doing a small hack (see [this article](http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/)). Replacing the `nav` with a `div` works fine, even with IE, even if the links had already a background before.

See http://jsfiddle.net/tsimbalar/gw686/embedded/result/

Comment: thanks @tsimbalar; to much wanting for jquery can make you forget on the basics. xD

Comment: @DoYouWantaWebsite haha, yes that happens ;) but it's good to always think if we can do things without javascript for users who have it disabled(does that still exist?)

Comment: can you also help me solve this thing without using the image-background technique? i forgot that i had another problem because if we do this technique; we have to background already. the first is the normal gradient blue background and the img for for our subnav.

Comment: @DoYouWanta I have updated the 2nd example with a case where links already have an image background. I can have the 2 images on top of each other, but it's a bit more work... go check it out !

Comment: Actually it works in FF, but not in IE ... I think is is related to the fact that IE does not know about HTML5 elements like 'nav' and does not know how to apply styles to it wihout a small hack (http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/) .... and it can not be applied properly in the jsfidle environment, I think ...

Comment: @DoYouWantaWebsite : great, consider marking your question as answered, then ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want some jQuery like this. May not be the most elegant solution but should set you in the right direction.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li").each(function() {
        if($(this).children("ul").length > 0) {
            var $link = $(this).find("a").first();
            var $newImg = $("<img src=\"li_gray.png\">");
            $link.addClass("current");
            $link.append($newImg);
        }
    })
});;
```